# What is %GetOptimizationStatus function in js file running in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I'm reading [this article](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) on optimization techniques and there's the following code:

```
//Function that contains the pattern to be inspected (using an `eval` statement)
function exampleFunction() {
    return 3;
    eval('');
}

function printStatus(fn) {
    switch(%GetOptimizationStatus(fn)) {
        case 1: console.log("Function is optimized"); break;
        case 2: console.log("Function is not optimized"); break;
        case 3: console.log("Function is always optimized"); break;
        case 4: console.log("Function is never optimized"); break;
        case 6: console.log("Function is maybe deoptimized"); break;
        case 7: console.log("Function is optimized by TurboFan"); break;
        default: console.log("Unknown optimization status"); break;
    }
}

//Fill type-info
exampleFunction();
// 2 calls are needed to go from uninitialized -> pre-monomorphic -> monomorphic
exampleFunction();

%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(exampleFunction);
//The next call
exampleFunction();

//Check
printStatus(exampleFunction);
```

I have two questions:

- The functions `%GetOptimizationStatus` and `%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall` are never defined, where do they come from?
- What does this phrase mean `2 calls are needed to go from uninitialized -> pre-monomorphic -> monomorphic` ?

Comment: Are you running your node App, with the specified flags?

Comment: I don't run node.js, my question is about the script

Comment: It kind of doesn't make any sense if your not running it in node.. The %GetOptimizationStatus, %OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall are of course injected by node when said flags are active.

Comment: And the monomorphic part is basically saying the optimiser won't kick in until it detects multi-use,..  After this TurboFan is activated.

Comment: @Keith, thanks, maybe you can then post it as an answer?

Comment: For your second question (please ask only one per post), see [Why do monomorphic and polymorphic matter in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37058643/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot for the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%GetOptimizationStatus` and `%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall` are injected into Node, when the specified optimization flags are set.

And the monomorphic part is basically saying the optimiser won't kick in until it detects multi-use,..  After this TurboFan is activated.

IOW: if you look at the output you will notice it call's  exampleFunction twice (with optimisation disabled), and it's only on the third try does the TurboFan kick in.